# Node-Webkit - Try enumerate file under directory from webkitdirectory input but return only directory path

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, node-webkit, nw.js

The title may be too long, but I wanted to **enumerate file names under selected directory from webkitdirectory `<input>`, but only returned the directory name**.

### HTML:

```
<input id="dialog-choose-photo-folder" type="file" webkitdirectory>
```

### Console Returned:

```
> document.getElementById("dialog-choose-photo-folder").files
    FileList {0: File, length: 1, item: function, clear: function, append: function}
      0: File
        lastModifiedDate: Tue Oct 07 2014 23:02:54 GMT+0800 (中國標準時間)
        name: "Pictures"
        path: "C:\Users\Daniel\Pictures"
        size: 40960
        type: ""
        webkitRelativePath: "Daniel/Pictures"
        __proto__: File
      length: 1
    __proto__: FileList
```

The `document.getElementById("dialog-choose-photo-folder").files` returned a length of `1` but there are actually many.

How comes it returned the directory name? Am I doing anything wrong? I even followed closely to https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/File-dialogs

I've seen the `nwdirectory` attribute and I believe mine behaved exactly like that, is it a bug?

If I'm doing everything wrong, I actually want to result of: http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/webkitdirectory/

Please help me! :(

Comment: My understanding is the same as yours, that `nwdirectory` should return the path to the dir, while `webkitdirectory` should return the list of files in the directory.  It looks to me like a bug in node-webkit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fighting with my own thoughts in my head, and asking a question on meta StackOverflow, I have decided to post this as an answer. :) If anyone has a better answer, I will accept it.

According to here: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/2571

> Note - this seems to work fine in 0.8.6. Also - looks like it worked earlier in 0.12 alpha but may have been broken when #2961 was fixed
>
> -chafey

This feature is broken. We should look forward for an update (not likely). The end. :)

---

### Update:

I forgot to mention how I overcame this problem. I simply used node.js.